# Running parse locally

Tags: node.js, parse-platform

I'm trying to run Parse locally,

```
> mongodb-runner start
  \ Starting a MongoDB deployment to test against...{ [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink 'C:\Users\xybrek\.mongodb\versions\mongodb-3.2.5-windows-64' -> 'C:\Users\xybrek\.mongodb\versions\mongodb-current']
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'symlink',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\xybrek\\.mongodb\\versions\\mongodb-3.2.5-windows-64',
  dest: 'C:\\Users\\xybrek\\.mongodb\\versions\\mongodb-current' }
```

And  I am getting that error. What does this error mean and how do we fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. Just run the command as root administrator which means you have to start the command prompt as administrator.